# Transversing a materialized view by path

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I get an array as shown below using this query:

```
  SELECT id, person_id, description, path FROM comment WHERE path <@ '0001' ORDER by path
```

My question is how am I suppose to use the to display the output as threaded? Do I check the first four numbers and increment to see if they are in the same level or is there something that I'm failing to understand?

```
[0] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 1
        [person_id] =&gt; 1
        [description] =&gt; a75e62536ca2687ae5817acb739e61f3
        [path] =&gt; 0001
    )

[1] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 2
        [person_id] =&gt; 2
        [description] =&gt; 010242f78cd5d41abb16a8ba488957a1
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0001.0001
    )

[2] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 3
        [person_id] =&gt; 2
        [description] =&gt; cdde38b2b13ee808ce5423cdf8d14bab
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0001.0001.0001
    )

[3] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 4
        [person_id] =&gt; 1
        [description] =&gt; 6b837ce73896fbd080bd0b93837ad537
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0001.0001.0002
    )

[4] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 5
        [person_id] =&gt; 5
        [description] =&gt; e5694a273ed95d36934cff48cd8fb12a
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0001.0001.0003
    )

[5] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 6
        [person_id] =&gt; 6
        [description] =&gt; 15b2ad371934352c0b16c5c1585f3d7d
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0002
    )

[6] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 7
        [person_id] =&gt; 6
        [description] =&gt; 2d1595f0c4ec527c601f404c7a272407
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0002.0001
    )

[7] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 8
        [person_id] =&gt; 6
        [description] =&gt; 8286c3bbe511d866e4e2ef4321a429d7
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0003
    )

[8] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 9
        [person_id] =&gt; 8
        [description] =&gt; dc455dd484220176d1d2198f84bdbc90
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0003.0001
    )

[9] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 10
        [person_id] =&gt; 9
        [description] =&gt; b8a8f41b224f900f6f5de0e591ba13b8
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0003.0002
    )

[10] =&gt; Array
    (
        [id] =&gt; 11
        [person_id] =&gt; 11
        [description] =&gt; ef132c4663961ff09ca61f40eec72697
        [path] =&gt; 0001.0003.0002.0001
    )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "display the output as threaded"? Please edit your question to show the table structure and some sample output of how you want the data displayed or ordered. Is the "path" column of the `ltree` data type or something else?

Comment: Isn't it a "materialized path" instead of a "materialized view" ?